# dynamically build and populate table with php array

Tags: php, arrays

let's say I have these two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
```

As you can see, my arrays have different lengths. What I'm trying to do is to input these array values into an HTML table with the first column containing the values coming from `$array1` and the second column containing the values coming from `$array2`. So, in this case right here, I should have a table of 10 rows (because `$array2` contains 10 elements) and 2 columns (because I have 2 arrays). Also, I cannot know in advance which array is going to have more elements than the other (so, `$array1` could be bigger than `$array2`, they could also have equal sizes). So, depending on which array has more elements, the number of rows in my table should adjust accordingly.

Any idea please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$a=count($array1);
$b=count($array2);
echo "<table border=1><tr><th>Array1</th><th>Array2</th></tr>";
if($a > $b)
{
    for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$array1[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$array2[$i]."</td></tr>";
    }
}
if($b > $a)
{
    for($i=0;$i<$b;$i++)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$array1[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$array2[$i]."</td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I get undefined offset error, but I can correct that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of some thing like below

this will give you atleast an idea of how to iterate them.

```
$array = array($array1,$arry2);

for($i = 0; $i < $array.length; $i++)
{

   $rows = $array[$i];

    for($j=0; $j< $rows.length; $rows++){
   }

}
```

i hope you can figure out the logic required from this . in case it doesnt work out post comment and we will walk through